# gRPC multiple services in cpp async server

Tags: grpc

I know there is an example `helloworld` program in `gRPC` source. However, being new to this, I don't understand how to write more than one async services in the server. The example [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.0.0/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_async_server.cc) talks about spawning new instances of a class to handle `SayHello` service calls.

1. How to add new services, for example `SayBye`, so that I can make calls to it from client?
2. How to make the server identify which service call was made by the client ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

See [this
thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/grpc-io/JpGURpAANss) and
the relevant
[example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/commit/7cd14c2b72c3acf8898164784999a9b96c7804ca).
The suggestion is to add a `bool` parameter to `CallData` (`hello_` in
this example), instantiate two `CallData` objects, one with `hello_ =
true`, and one with `hello_ = false`, and have each one request a
different RPC.

```cpp
if (hello_) {
  service_->RequestSayHello(...);
} else {
  service_->RequestSayBye(...);
}
```

For more than two types of calls, you could achieve the same behavior
with an `enum` instead of a `bool`.

A more flexible approach would be to have a different `CallData`-like
class for each RPC. However when you get a tag from `cq_->Next()`, you
know that it is a pointer to an object of one of these classes, but you
don't know its exact type. To overcome this, you can have them all
inherit from a class with a virtual `Proceed()` member function,
implement it as needed in each subclass, and when you get a tag, cast it
as `CallData` and call `Proceed()`.

```cpp
class CallData {
 public:
  virtual void Proceed() = 0;
};

class HelloCallData final : public CallData {...};
class ByeCallData final : public CallData {...};

...
new HelloCallData(...);
new ByeCallData(...);
cq_->Next(&tag, &ok);
static_cast<CallData*>(tag)->Proceed();
...
```

Comment: could you expand on this? is there a code example that does this? I'm trying to create an AsyncServer that does something like what you're describing with multiple types of completely different RPC calls.

Comment: @davidawad You can take a look [here](https://github.com/forkbong/crocks/blob/master/src/server/async_server.cc).
This is a project I was working on at the time I wrote the answer, and it does what I'm describing.
I suggest you start with [this commit](https://github.com/forkbong/crocks/commit/a74d92f055f4d3aa4646bb6709e7174b340523a5),
which introduces the asynchronous server and is much simpler.
If you need further help feel free to ask, but I haven't written any C++ since then, and I'm not sure if I'll be able to help.